# "makepkg" (manjaro) can't detect already installed JDK/JRE

Tags: linux, build, package, archlinux, manjaro

I’m using GraalVM instead of ordinary JVM. I ran makepkg but it's giving me error of missing JRE dependency  even tho i already have graalVM jdk installed.

When I’m going for makepkg in manjaro, I’m getting an error of missing dependency.

> ==> Missing dependencies:
> → java-runtime>=17.0

Already have a JDK

> echo $PATH

> /home/I0bit/graalvm-jdk-17.0.7+8.1//bin:/home/I0bit/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/I0bit/graalvm-jdk-17.0.7+8.1/bin

so, I edited depends in PKGBUILD to ‘graalvm-jdk>=17.0.7’ , also tried ‘graalvm-jdk>=17.0.7+8.1’ and few other similar things but makepkg still isn’t able to detect jdk.
Even tried including export JAVA_HOME path in PKGBUILD but it is still giving me missing dependency error.